# Foursqaure API how to search by location with specific keywords

Tags: jquery, api, foursquare

I am trying to replicate something like what [travefy.com](https://travefy.com) has when you try to plan and trip and then go into actvities.
I have been playing around with the API in Jquery but i cannot find a get method that gives takes the location and specific keywords like the search like travefy does

So far this is what I have tried

```
    <body>
    Location <input type="text" id="locationid"> </br>
    Activity  <input type="text" id="activityid"></br>
    <button id="locate">Submit</button>


   <div id="names">
   </div>
   <script>
   var clicked = 1

   $( "#locate" ).click(function() {
   $( "#names" ).empty();
    $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?        near='+$('#locationid').val()+'&ll=40.7,-74&query='+$('#activityid').val()+'&client_id=2POUFAUU4ZBJ2MTDOY3S2YHR2NIT52FYW0LUTPHBMNTJFJNQ&client_secret=YFDZI1YWV3ZI5S5SPM2DZJEQIEBPIDJ5XFZBWTIKIQZVQNYM&v=20120101',
    function(data) {

        $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
            $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+venues.id+'/photos?&client_id=2POUFAUU4ZBJ2MTDOY3S2YHR2NIT52FYW0LUTPHBMNTJFJNQ&client_secret=YFDZI1YWV3ZI5S5SPM2DZJEQIEBPIDJ5XFZBWTIKIQZVQNYM&v=20120101',
                function(data) {

                 if (data.response.photos.count> 0){
                    console.log(data)
                     content = '<p><img src='+data.response.photos.groups[1].items[0].url+' /></p>';

                    $(content).appendTo("#names");
                        }


                });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `query` parameter that you can supply with a venues/search call help? You can find a full list of params in our [endpoint docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search), and an example of what this looks like in our [getting started search guide](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search)

Answer (score 0):

[Travefy.com](https://travefy.com) builds the autocomplete list using the "venues/categories" call combined with the distinct names returned by the "venues/suggestcompletion" call.

The selected search string is then passed into the ["venues/explore"](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) as the "query" parameter.

Additionally - Using the "venues/explore" call instead of "venues/search" would also return a primary image with the results if you add the parameter venuePhotos=1.  Using that parameter would make it unnecessary for you to loop through the results to get the details for each if you are only doing that to get the image.